# Break row after reaching end of DIV container

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have the following code where the images are fetched from the database. It keeps going breaking the `DIV` and `overflows`. What I want is when the images reach the end of the `DIV` it should break and start a new line. But I have no idea as how to achieve this. Please help me guys.

## Code

```
<div class="inline-flex">
    <?php while($faf = $prooq->fetch()){ extract($faf); ?>
       <div class="image-container"> <img class="myThumb" id="myImg" src="proofs/<?php echo $pr_image; ?>" alt="" width="160" height="100">
          <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)<br>
          <span><?php echo date('jS M, Y (h:i a)', strtotime($pr_uptime)); ?></span></div>
       </div>
       <div id="myModal" class="modal"> <span class="close">&times;</span> <img class="modal-content" id="modalImg">
          <div id="caption"></div>
       </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.image-container {
    width: 163px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0px 0px 65px 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-right: 13px;
}

.image-text {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.image-text span {
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 9px;
}
.inline-flex {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: did you try `.image-container {display: inline-block;}` ? and I think you need to set width for `inline-flex`.

Comment: Yes I did.. but it did not work...!

Comment: width for inline-flex is set to 100%

Comment: could you show a css stylesheet of the page?

Comment: updated.... refresh page.....

Comment: Instead of setting `width: 163px;`. Use `width: 33%;`. 3 images will come in a row as 100% width is given for `inline-flex`. It will automatically break after 3 images.

Comment: tried... not working........

Comment: If you could create a JSFiddle or Codepen with your generated HTML and CSS, that'd be helpful.

Comment: _“width for inline-flex is set to 100%”_ – then why is it inline-flex and not just flex in the first place? Anyway, `flex-wrap` should be the property you are looking for.

Comment: Did you find your answer, if yes, mark the one that helped you

Comment: @SuperBoy yes I found my solution but its different... not matching with any of the answers..

Comment: @ShubhamJha Oh okay, answer your own post then to provide the good answer ! :)

Comment: @SuperBoy good idea boy :)

Comment: @SuperBoy done.. have look.. :)

Comment: I just checked, nice ! But you should mark it as an answer

Comment: done @SuperBoy .. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my solution. Added an extra DIV with class `.proof-container` with property `position: relative;` and wrapped all elements inside it and added a property `float: left;` to `.image-container`. That's it. Below is the code:

CSS:

```
.image-container {
    width: 197px;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 0px 0px 65px 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.proof-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="proof-container">
        <?php while($faf = $prooq->fetch()){ extract($faf); ?>
        <div class="image-container">
          <img class="myThumb" id="myImg" src="proofs/<?php echo $pr_image; ?>" alt="" width="160" height="100">
          <div class="image-text"><?php echo $mem_uname; ?> ($8.75)<br>
            <span><?php echo date('jS M, Y (h:i a)', strtotime($pr_uptime)); ?></span></div>
        </div>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal"> <span class="close">&times;</span> <img class="modal-content" id="modalImg">
          <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using display : **table**

```
.inline-flex {
     width: 100%;
     display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `display: inline-block; float: left;` to `.image-container`

```css
.image-container {
    width: 163px;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 0px 0px 65px 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-right: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.image-text {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.image-text span {
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 9px;
}
.inline-flex {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-flex">
   <div class="image-container"> <img class="myThumb" id="myImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-3.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="100">
          <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)<br>
          <span>date('jS M, Y (h:i a)', strtotime($pr_uptime));</span></div>
       </div>
       </div>
   <div class="image-container"> <img class="myThumb" id="myImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-3.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="100">
          <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)<br>
          <span>date('jS M, Y (h:i a)', strtotime($pr_uptime));</span></div>
       </div>
   <div class="image-container"> <img class="myThumb" id="myImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-3.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="100">
          <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)<br>
          <span>date('jS M, Y (h:i a)', strtotime($pr_uptime));</span></div>
       </div>
   <div class="image-container"> <img class="myThumb" id="myImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-3.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="100">
          <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)<br>
          <span>date('jS M, Y (h:i a)', strtotime($pr_uptime));</span></div>
       </div>
   <div class="image-container"> <img class="myThumb" id="myImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-3.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="100">
          <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)<br>
          <span>date('jS M, Y (h:i a)', strtotime($pr_uptime));</span></div>
       </div>
   <div class="image-container"> <img class="myThumb" id="myImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-3.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="100">
          <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)<br>
          <span>date('jS M, Y (h:i a)', strtotime($pr_uptime));</span></div>
       </div>
```